# Как в jinja2 отключить экранирование тегов?

Tags: flask, jinja2

Мне нужно вставить в страницу блок сгенерированный функцией. И в нём разумеется используется html разметка. Делаю так `{{ my_func() }}`. Должно быть `<b>2</b>540186963`, однако `&lt;b&gt;2&lt;/b&gt;540186963`. Как выключить это экранирование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template Designer Documentation: Working with Automatic Escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping)

```
{{ my_func()|safe }}
```